# "Can't access a Disposed object" during Serial Port Data being displayed in Rich text Box

Tags: c#, serial-port, dispose

I am trying to make a Serial Data Plotter using C#. I have an Arduino acting as Serial Data Streaming device and it is continuously sending data to PC. My application is supposed to receive that data and Display it in Rich Text Box. Further application is far complex but this is the basic building block.

Now, Data is received correctly if data rate is slow. I can Connect and Disconnect Serial port using Provided button.

Problem arises when data rate is fast. During Data receive, If I try to disconnect,it throws error of "Cannot access Disposed Object". I am posting Code for the same:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Serial_Port_reference
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool cnctBtn_state = false;

        public SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
        string[] portNames;

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
        delegate void SetIntCallback(int value);

        bool spClosesd = false;

        private void SetoutputRtb(string text)
        {
            if (outputRtb.InvokeRequired)
            {

                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetoutputRtb);
                Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                outputRtb.AppendText(text);
                outputRtb.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Serial Port Receive Interrupt
        public void serialReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string temp = null;
            try
            {
                temp = sp.ReadTo("#");
                SetoutputRtb(temp);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
            }


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cnctBtn.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            cnctBtn.ForeColor = Color.White;

            sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialReceived);
            portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            foreach (string ports in portNames)
            {
                portCombo.Items.Add(ports);
            }

            portCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;



        }

        private void cnctBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cnctBtn_state == false)
            {
                sp.PortName = portCombo.SelectedItem.ToString();
                sp.BaudRate = int.Parse(baudCombo.SelectedItem.ToString());
                sp.DataBits = 8;
                sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                sp.Parity = Parity.None;

                try
                {
                    sp.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
                    return;
                }

                cnctBtn.Text = "Disconnect";
                cnctBtn.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;

                cnctBtn_state = true;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    sp.DiscardInBuffer();

                    //sp.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
                    return;
                }

                cnctBtn.Text = "Connect";
                cnctBtn.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;

                cnctBtn_state = false;
            }
        }

        private void sendTxtButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sp.Write(sendTxtBox.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
            }

            sendTxtBox.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

I have used Invoke method to make Cross-thread calls to write in RTB and that's where program halts.

I tried a lot of different things as per my understanding as well Suggestions given on different forums but none of them are specifically related to Serial port so I am not able to implement them. I understand nature of problem but Don't know how to implement safe method to Catch ObjectDisposeExceptions or mainly prevent them. I am kind of new to C# programming so might need a little bit more explanation on programming part. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pay attention to the stack trace of the exception (let your exception handlers not only output the exception message, but also let them output the stack trace). It will tell you precisely which code line threw the exception (assuming you are running a debug build). Either your SerialPort got disposed, or your outputRtb control perhaps went AWOL...

Comment: @mjwills Yea as it is redundant to use. Control.close() is essentially Control.Dispose(true) so doesn't make much difference. Although, I tried both of them with no change in output whatsoever.

Comment: @elgonzo Yes. Every time it is stuck on outputRtb's invoke function line.

Comment: If `Invoke(d, new object[] { text });` throws the “_Can't access a Disposed object_” exception, you will need to debug and analyze your code with regard to how it works with this `outputRtb` field and any parent UI container this control is within. Because (if i understood your last comment correctly) something in your code removes/closes/disposes/does "funny things" with `outputRtb`.

Comment: `Control.close()` Where is that called in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you close the connection by sp.Dispose() ? It's currently commented out in your code.  Normally you'd want to use Close() -- it will discard both input & output buffers.

But I think that you may be receiving data and the DataReceived event is firing but not necessarily delivered when you do the Dispose.  When it is delivered, your sp serial port has already been disposed so I'm suspicous you are getting the error on sp.ReadTo() in your serialReceived() function.  In fact, looking closer, when (if) you do a Close() you will get one more event -- the "end-of-file" indication will cause the DataReceived event.

You could set sp = null after disposal, then check that in the serialReceived() function before reading.  This is a good practice anyway.  As you probably know, the DataReceived event will run serialReceived in a different thread.  I'm not sure if it could be scheduled before between the Dispose() call and the sp=null.

So, I think the best thing is to disconnect the event before calling Close():

```
sp.DataReceived += serialReceived.
```

Another thing -- I've not used ReadTo() before, but  it appears that it will block until that character is received.  Is that what you expect?  If a character comes in, your event will fire, but that thread will block until the '#' is received.  I think a more typical DataReceived event handler would read and handle all bytes available, and parse it out.

Comment: As per .NET documentation, Dispose() has Close() in it's declaration so they are redundant. Although, Error remains same in use of either of them!

As per debugger, Program is stuck in Invoke function. So DataReceived event is not being a problem. Yet I will try to follow steps suggested by you as they sound like safer way of dealing with events. I will update the results.

About ReadTo(), My data packet is no more than 8-10 bytes so Program will not be stuck for long time. I use Read() but they are not good during continuous data stream.